# Python scipy.signal.periodogram() optimization

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to analyze a signal and I need to compute multiple periodograms in a `for` loop. When I run:

```
scipy.signal.periodogram(data_arr,fs=sampling_frequency, window=some_window)
```

on my data array which has a `len() = 3456410` it only take ~3 seconds or so. HOWEVER, when I run a truncated version of my data `data_arr[some_number:some_number]`, which has a significantly smaller size than the original `data_arr`(about an order of magnitude), using `scipy.signal.periodogram()` it take ~3 minutes to run the same process on less data.

I have also tried this using the `spectrum.DaniellPeriodogram()` and it does the same thing.

I assume the issue lies in the back end somewhere, possibly using python's `[:]` method to truncate my data. Ive also checked out the scipys source code for the function, but I cant seem to find the issue. Any suggestions as to why it takes longer to process my truncated data vs the entire data array?

Comment: What is the length of `data_arr[some_number:some_number]`?  At the heart of the periodogram calculation is a fast fourier transform, and the time required for an FFT depends on the length--best is a power of 2, worst is a large prime number.  Try using the `nfft` argument, using a power of 2.

Comment: Ah! I didnt think of that, I knew that a FFT was was happening in the back end, but I didnt think to check prime vs. non-prime. Since the length of `data_arr` truncated is in fact prime number, truncating it to `data_arr[some_number:some_number-1]` fixed the issue. I appreciate the help.